# SQL Date field & unique ID combination to generate running months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to generate running months in sql using date & id field combination.
need to generate the 'Month' column format.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to Images of data isn't helpful. Post the data as what it is, `text`. When you do though, please remember to ask a question as well and show your attempts. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service; you don't request the users to do the work for you, you *ask* the **volunteers** for help on a problem you've tried and failed to solve yourself

Comment: explain it more. you have a table and you want to combine `date, Id and Month`. im i wrong ?

Comment: Please write more data about your problem. What do you mean by "running months"? And you said unique ID but your ID column is not unique.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: The question is ill-formatted, for sure, but it's very clear what the OP is asking. This is a new contributor, give him a chance to edit the question instead of closing it after only 20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feed back and suggestions. I am very new to Stack Overflow , from now on I will follow the rules!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
WITH cte
AS (   SELECT *, MONTH(Date) AS monthNum
       FROM tablename),
     cte2
AS (   SELECT *,
           FIRST_VALUE(cte.monthNum) OVER (PARTITION BY date
                                           ORDER BY ID) AS firstval,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id) AS ROWNUM
       FROM cte)
SELECT ID,
    DATE,
    (cte2.firstval + cte2.ROWNUM) - 1 AS 'Month'
FROM cte2;
```

The above code will extract Month and increment the value by 1 for same ID.

Comment: way to over complicate things :-)

Comment: Yes thanks this works want to increment in the same way : )

Comment: @Prasad If this answer worked for you, can you please accept it by clicking on the check mark located besides the answer. Happy to help!

Comment: I was in the process of writing an answer when this question got closed, couldn't post it - but here's a link to a [simpler query](https://rextester.com/MOB35083) on rextester.